# How to use two ngFor in html Angular 4?

Tags: html, angular

In my angular 4 project in response of a request from server I get two different arrays and in template I want to use both of them. the controller code is:

```
this.contractService.getOwnerContract()
  .subscribe(
    res => {
     this.contracts = res.contracts;
     this.users= res.users;
  })
```

and in html I want to use two ngFor to use contract and users properties:

```
<div class="col-md-12 property-list-box" *ngFor="let contct of contracts ; let usr of users">
  <div>{{contct.id}}</div>
  <div>{{usr.id}}</div>
</div>
```

but this html code that I wrote doesn't work. What is the best solution?
Thanks for helping in advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do these two arrays always have the same number of elements? If so you can iterate over one of them, and keep track of index

```
<div class="col-md-12 property-list-box" *ngFor="let contract of contracts ; let i = index">
  <div>{{contracts[i].id}}</div>
  <div>{{users[i].id}}</div>
</div>
```

If they don't always have the same number of elements you'll need 2 `ngFor` directives

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge both the arrays and store in a variable and use the variable in your ngFor on the template.

Or you could a pipe to "merge" your two arrays into a single array  and then you can iterate over it
Here is a sample:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'concat'
})
export class ConcatPipe {
  transform(arr1, arr2) {
    var arr = [];
    arr1.forEach((elt, i) => {
      arr.push({ state: elt, name: arr2[i] });
    });
  }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
<div class="col-md-12 property-list-box"*ngFor="let contract of contracts | merge:users"  >
  {{contract.id}} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `index` for next array.

```
<div class="col-md-12 property-list-box" *ngFor="let contct of contracts; index as i">
  <div>{{contct.id}}</div>
  <div>{{users[i].id}}</div>
</div>
```

See more : https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Answer (score 0):

If your both arrays have equal size then you can simple use any one of the Array and use the index for another. For example:

{{user.name}}   {{ contacts[i].your_another_array_key}}

If array is not equal in size then you have to manipulate in some other fashion so it can be iterable in a single list like custom array.